# In sqlite I would do, But how in mongodb c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, sqlite

So for sqlite I would just do:

```
var d = new ConnectionHandler();
            var writeData =
                $"UPDATE `Books` SET Book_Author = @Book_Author WHERE ID = 1";


            d.OpenCnx();
            using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(writeData, d.cnx))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Book_Author", $"New Book owner");
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

but for Mongodb for c# what would be the equivalent, or how would I do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some inspiration for updating a document in the quick-tour documentation provided on the MongoDB site: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/getting_started/quick_tour/

Just look at the *Updating Document*  section.

But to save a click you can use the following code as an inspiration:

```
// Setup the connection to the database
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
var database = client.GetDatabase("Library");
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("books");

// Create a filter to find the book with ID 1
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("ID", 1);
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("Book_Author", "New Book owner");
collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

I hope this helps.